# Contribution=Membership+Donation incorrect for CiviCRM 4.7.12 on WordPress 4.6.1

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contributions, receipts

I'm setting up a Signup, Renew, Donate page for both Membership signup/renewal and adding in an optional donation. I first tried setting the Financial Type = Membership. Everything worked fine, except the Membership and Donation were consolidated into one fee, not separate despite checking "Separate Membership Payment" when setting up the page. Also, on the receipt to the member, the two fees are added together, so they can't see how much was a donation (fully tax deductible) and how much was a membership (only partially deductible).

So, I tried setting Financial Type = "Donations" and now everything works correctly in the database regarding both separate donation and membership entries, as well as getting the membership info correct. If an offline payment is selected, the invoice nicely breaks out the membership and donation information - see attached. HOWEVER, for an ONline payment, there is a separate email receipt for both the donation and the membership - see attached. The donation receipt is correct. However, the membership receipt shows TWICE the amount, because the membership is counted BOTH as a membership and now a redundant donation - see attached. If the optional donation is not included, the membership receipt still is double-counted, which will certainly create confusion to members.

Is this a configuration issue that someone else has solved? OR, is it possibly a bug in generating the email receipt. Everything works perfectly except the separate e-mail for the membership. Ideally, the email receipt, like the invoice, would simply show both items with the correct total.

Thanks for any help on this.

The screenshot below shows correct reply on our website. Going into the CiviCRM database, a $17 Contribution is recorded as a donation, and a $30 membership is also recorded and the member's membership status is accurately updated.
[image: Correct screen reply]
<sub>(source: [sdcbcdream.org](http://sdcbcdream.org/images/MembershipDonationScreenReply_CORRECT.png))</sub>

Below is the corresponding incorrect Membership Receipt in email. Note that the membership fee of $30 is listed also as a contribution, so that the total $60 is exactly DOUBLE.
[image: Incorrect Membership Receipt in email]
<sub>(source: [sdcbcdream.org](http://sdcbcdream.org/images/MembershipOnlyReceipt_INCORRECT.png))</sub>

Below we see that the Donation Receipt in email is perfect.
[image: Correct Donation Receipt in email]
<sub>(source: [sdcbcdream.org](http://sdcbcdream.org/images/DonationOnlyReceipt_CORRECT.png))</sub>

Finally, the Invoice below generated for an offline payment (Pay Later) also correctly breaks out the total plus each item. It would be great if a receipt like this could be combine into just one receipt e-mail, although not necessary. We just don't want it to look like the Membership cost was double the actual.
[image: Correct Offline Invoice in email]
<sub>(source: [sdcbcdream.org](http://sdcbcdream.org/images/MembershipDonationOfflineInvoice_CORRECT.png))</sub>

Comment: This is CiviCRM 4.7.12 hosted on WordPress 4.6.1

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now in the latest 4.7 - I know this for a fact because I QAed it!

You'll still get two receipts - but the math now adds up.

Comment: Thank you, Karin! That's just the motivation we need to do the 4.7.14 update.

Comment: After updating to 4.7.14, the problem with the receipts is fixed... GREAT! That's only the good news, though. When a person selects a membership and enters an optional donation, the math on the Confirm Contribution page "may" now be incorrect. In testing, one tester ALWAYS has the correct Membership amount, but the Donation amount is the SUM of the Membership and Donation. If you click Make Contribution, that is also how it is billed and recorded, so the user sends more money than planned. This was not a problem in Civi 4.7.12 - only the receipt was messed up. The transaction was good.

Comment: Elaborating on the above comment, we had 3 people test this with Civi 4.7.14 [note Dummy payment processor ;)]. Two of the testers had no issues. Confirm Contribution page correct, transaction in the database correct, receipts correct [separate emails for Membership and Donation]. However, one of the testers ALWAYS had the incorrect behavior above. So, it somehow is user-dependent, but doesn't seem random. I will add that the 2 successful testers also had Administrator privileges in Wordpress. The one failed tester had no Wordpress login whatsoever and we don't demand that our members make one

Comment: One more thing, the one failed tester got the same behavior whether our Contribution Page started as Financial Type = Membership and then ADDED Donation, or if we started as Financial Type = Donation and then ADDED Membership. In Civi 4.7.12, the behavior was different.

Comment: Hey Karl - we had two CiviCRM contributors test a very specific scenario but I'm not surprised to hear you are still observing some issues with 4.7 under some conditions. Best to add another JIRA ticket.

Comment: Karin - I am new to these support discussions. Are you submitting a JIRA ticket? I'm not sure I have access to CiviCRM's JIRA. Also, I have a couple screen shots. It would be easiest to send them through regular email. My email is rudnick.cooper@gmail.com

Comment: Karin - btw - if you have a test environment with the Dummy payment processor enabled, I would be happy to test a Membership + Donation page as a totally independent person. It still may be there are some configuration options that need to be tweaked on our Contribution Page.

Comment: Do those testers have same membership status prior to submitting? (Just one variable that may not have been considered)

Comment: petednz - All 3 testers had active, non-expired memberships.

Comment: Karin - We have now gone live. No test environment anymore. To be safe, we just set up a separate Membership and Donate page, but ultimately we want an optional donation with any membership signup/renewal. I CAN set up a parallel test environment on a test domain, but we've been so busy deploying our first Wordpress+CiviCRM site that I need to take a break for a few days. Let me know if that would help. I've got mirrors in xampp on a windows and linux laptop, but that won't help this issue. Let me know if you need me to do that for work to continue on this issue.